# How to kick all players

Tags: lua, roblox

Code is not working

```
workspace.WindowEvent.Changed:Connect(function(hit)
  local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
  if workspace.WindowEvent.Value == true then
    wait(5)
    if workspace.WindowEvent.Value == true then
      plr:Kick("asdf")
    end
  end
end)
```

WindowEvent.Value means boolvalue

I need to kick all players by serverside script

Comment: Heyo, it's not enough to say that something isn't working. Be specific, what exactly isn't working? Are you getting any error messages? What do you expect to happen? What is actually happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though kicking all players in-game doesn't sound like a very good idea, here's how you would do it.

`<Player Reference> --this can be the Players service`
`:GetPlayers()`

With that, you get the in-game players.
Now you iterate and kick each of them. You will end up with something like:

```
local players = game:GetService("Players")

for i,v in ipairs (players:GetPlayers()) do
    v:kick("reason") --v is the player instance/object
end
```